# what can I do to overcome my love handles?

Tags: weight-loss, workout, bodyweight-exercises

I am worried about my Love Handles.They are increasing day by day .Please suggest me some exercise to make them at 0 level.Thanks

Comment: One of my favourite body-building quotes of all time: *"A six pack is made in the kitchen"*

Answer (score 1):

Exercise alone won't help you here as you cannot spot reduce fat in any location on your body. There is no specific exercise plan that will help you in this instance.

You need to create a calorie deficit by making nutritional changes (*mostly*) to lose ***total*** body fat.

To accelerate and improve the process you should develop a complimentary balanced exercise routine. With an appropriate mix of resistance training (*to preserve muscle mass and influence muscle shape*), cardiovascular training (*for heart health and a fat oxidation boost, because you can't do just resistance training*) and mobility training (*to maintain joint health, range of motion and low threshold motor function*).

You should exercise largely because it's healthy and supportive of a calorie deficit but you'll always be able to create a bigger deficit with nutrition moreso than exercise. That being said, nutrition + exercise always produces better results than either on their own, even nutrition-only-changes.

Hopefully your body pulls off your body fat in the same locations it last put it on, but it doesn't always work like that either. Sadly. Keep up the exercise routine and develop good nutrition skills long after you've achieved the reduction/elimination of the love handles.